# How to npm start a React app created with create-react-app in goormIDE?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am new to web development and I am trying to get my first React app running. I am using goormIDE as a cloud environment. I have Node.js and npm installed and so far I did:

1. `npm install npx`
2. `npx create-react-app my-app`
3. `cd my-app`
4. `npm start` and it successfully compiled

When I go to http://localhost:3000, I get the "This site can't be reached" error (`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`).

To hopefully fix this, I changed my firewall settings to 'allow port 3000' as an inbound rule. No luck.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

EDIT: I have also tried via IP http://XXX.XXX.X.X:3000/

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific: do you mean you're running this on some remote server, and you're now trying to connect to that? Or are you installing this _locally_ and `http://localhost:3000` doesn't work _on your own computer_?

Comment: try another port instead of 3000, try 45632 for example and then run local server and try it on local again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you specified that you are new to web development and that you are using *goormIDE*, it would be best for you to use the "Template" *goormIDE* feature for React.

***goormIDE* is a container-based cloud environment**. You have most probably created a container and you are trying to run React from command line from inside that container. This will not work, because:

1. The container is in the cloud, it won't answer on `localhost` but to the IP.
2. Opening firewall from inside a container is not enough to expose its ports. It will require some further configuration, which is an advanced topic that you should not tackle for now, being that you are new to web development.

Follow this [tutorial from goormIDE](https://blog.goorm.io/starting_the_goormide_eng/#1-template) to properly create a project using the Template feature.

Comment: Thanks for your help!